# Android Room compile-time warning about column in foreign key not part of an index. What does it mean?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm using Android's Room Persistence Library from the Android Architecture Components recently announced at Google I/O. Things seem to be working, but I'm getting the following error:

> Warning:tagId column references a foreign key but it is not part of an
>   index. This may trigger full table scans whenever parent table is
>   modified so you are highly advised to create an index that covers this
>   column.

My database has 3 tables: `Note`, `Tag`, and `JoinNotesTags`. Notes to Tags is a many-to-many relationship, hence the JoinNotesTags table to handle the mapping. The tables are straightforward:

- `Note.id` and `Tag.id` are both primary keys
- `JoinNotesTags.noteId` references `Note.id`
- `JoinNotesTags.tagId` references `Tag.id`

The foreign key constraints are defined on the `JoinNotesTags` table. For reference, here is the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the `JoinNotesTags` table:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `JoinNotesTags` (
    `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    `noteId` INTEGER, 
    `tagId` INTEGER, 
    FOREIGN KEY(`noteId`) REFERENCES `Note`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE , 
    FOREIGN KEY(`tagId`) REFERENCES `Tag`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION 
)"
```

And here is the corresponding `@Entity` annotation for that class:

```
@Entity(
        indices = arrayOf(Index(value = *arrayOf("noteId", "tagId"), unique = true)),
        foreignKeys = arrayOf(
                ForeignKey(
                        entity = Note::class,
                        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                        childColumns = arrayOf("noteId"),
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
                ForeignKey(
                        entity = Tag::class,
                        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                        childColumns = arrayOf("tagId"))
        )
)
```

As you can see from the `@Entity` annotation, `tagId` *is* included in a composite unique index along with `noteId`. I've confirmed that this index is correctly defined in the auto-generated json schema file as well:

```
"CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_JoinNotesTags_noteId_tagId` 
    ON `JoinNotesTags` (`noteId`, `tagId`)"
```

So, my question: Is this warning just a bug in the (still-alpha-release) Room Library -- i.e. the compile-time analysis is missing the fact that `tagId` is part of this composite index? Or do I really have an indexing problem that I need to resolve in order to avoid full table scans?

Comment: We need to see your _table_ definitions, not your Java code.  Specifically, I believe the error is not that the `tagId` column does not have an index, but that it refers to a foreign key which is not indexed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, question updated to include the table definition for `JoinNotesTags`. But for the record, `Tag.id` is a primary key. Besides, the warning says the issue is with the `tagId` column -- not the column in the parent table that it references (`Tag.id`).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you modify the `Tag` table, the database might need to lookup corresponding rows in the `JoinNotesTags` table. To be efficient, this [requires an index](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) on the `tagId` column.

Your composite index is not useful for that; because of the [way how indexes work](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html), the column(s) to be searched must be the leftmost column(s) in the index.

You should add an index on only the `tagId` column.
(You could swap the order of the columns in the composite index, but then you'd have the same problem with `noteId`.)

Comment: Can you add a sample illustration

Comment: To quote you: `You should add an index on only the tagId column`. Does this mean that noteId and tagId should be separate indices.?

Comment: @AshishKrishnan Yes, both should be the leftmost column in an index.

Comment: Gotcha!. Thanks.

Answer (score 86):

When in kotlin code:

*Before*

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "question_id")
var questionId: Long
```

*After*

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "question_id", index = true) //just add index = true
var questionId: Long
```

Comment: This worked for me. The answer could be simplified for readability with just the before and after of the `@ColumnInfo` line. The rest, especially Retrofit's `@Expose` and `@SerializedName`, are irrelevant and in most cases wouldn't be used in DB entities.

Answer (score 54):

You need to add index to columns for faster queries
Here is an example

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index("artist_id")})
public class Artist{
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "artist_id")
    public String id;
    public String name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this error is coming even if the index are properly defined , then there is some other compilation error other than this one. To fix it just comment the code which defines foreign keys in relationship table , and make project , and fix the other compilation errors and uncomment the given code.