# Android Room Database relation issue

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I would like to make a relation between two tables and I have an issue when doing this.

My first entity is:

```
@Entity(tableName = "rooms_table")
data class RoomsEntity(
@PrimaryKey
val room_id: Int,
val room_name: String,
val last_message: String,
val room_image: String,
val last_date: Date?,
val new_counter: Int
) {
constructor() : this(0, "","", "", null,0)
}
```

Second entity is:

```
@Entity(
tableName = "subscribers_table",
foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
    entity = RoomsEntity::class,
    parentColumns = arrayOf("subscriber_id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf ("room_id"),
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
 ) ]
 )
 data class SubscribersEntity(
 @PrimaryKey
val subscriber_id: Int,
val room_id: Int,
val subscriber_name: String,
val subscriber_image: String
) {
constructor() : this(0, 0, "", "")
}
```

I have this error when building my project:

```
"room_id column references a foreign key but it is not part of an index. This may trigger full table scans whenever parent table is modified so you are highly advised to create an index that covers this column."
```

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480761/android-room-compile-time-warning-about-column-in-foreign-key-not-part-of-an-ind